# Mininet's CLI get error:Error setting resource limits. Mininet's performance may be affected

Tags: mininet

I'm new to mininet,I try two ways to install the lastest mininet:

- sudo apt-get install mininet
- install mininet by source code

I get this message: `Error setting resource limits. Mininet's performance may be affected` when I using `sudo mn` command to start the mininet CLI.

what is the message mean,I'm not limit any resource or my machine is not good enough?I see the [issue](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/issues/529) like this,but I'm not docker.

Answer (score 1):

I know your aren't using docker but ***for anyone who use Docker and end up being here:***

As you can see in @rechard answer, this warning appears when mininet can't set some network parameters to increase arp table. To fix this issue in docker you could share host network parameters with docker container.

You can find complete Dockerfile and docker-compose file [here](https://github.com/soreana/docker-mininet).

Answer (score 0):

I get the anwser,because my ubuntu version is 3.0.13-100,a bug in this version.if you want to solve this problem,you need to update your kernl version

the bug is when you run the command like this:

`$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1=128`

get this error message:

`error: "Invalid argument" setting key "net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1"`

this bug in version 3.0.13-96 to 3.0.13-100,the detail view this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1634892)

when mininet start,It will run the fixLimits() function:

`def fixLimits():
    "Fix ridiculously small resource limits."
    debug( "*** Setting resource limits\n" )
    try:
        rlimitTestAndSet( RLIMIT_NPROC, 8192 )
        rlimitTestAndSet( RLIMIT_NOFILE, 16384 )
        #Increase open file limit
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'fs.file-max', 10000 )
        #Increase network buffer space
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.core.wmem_max', 16777216 )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.core.rmem_max', 16777216 )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem', '10240 87380 16777216' )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.tcp_wmem', '10240 87380 16777216' )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.core.netdev_max_backlog', 5000 )
        #Increase arp cache size
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1', 4096 )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2', 8192 )
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3', 16384 )
        #Increase routing table size
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'net.ipv4.route.max_size', 32768 )
        #Increase number of PTYs for nodes
        sysctlTestAndSet( 'kernel.pty.max', 20000 )
    # pylint: disable=broad-except
    except Exception:
        warn( "*** Error setting resource limits. "
              "Mininet's performance may be affected.\n" )
    # pylint: enable=broad-except`